# Pandas concat function gives ValueError : Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

```
result = df1.append(df2)
finalDf = pd.concat([principal_Df, result[['label']]], axis=1)

print(principal_Df.shape) //gives (12390, 5)
print(result.shape) // gives (12390, 9)
```

The concat line gives

> raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply
>   {implied}") ValueError: Shape of passed values is (18585, 6), indices
>   imply (12390, 6)

I am not understanding why it says 18585. Is there any other way to concatenate? Please help.

Edit:
I think I found the issue.

Printing result gives me the below

```
      label
0       1.0
1       1.0
2       1.0
3       1.0
4       1.0
     ...
6190    0.0
6191    0.0
6192    0.0
6193    0.0
6194    0.0
[12390 rows x 1 columns]
```

and printing principal_Df gives

```
      principal component 1  ...  principal component 5
0                  -3.815308  ...              -0.921742
1                  -0.192024  ...              -0.449291
2                  -1.755755  ...               0.603834
3                  -0.663780  ...               0.711707
4                   1.288255  ...               1.115953
                      ...  ...                    ...
12385               0.819819  ...               0.534367
12386               1.343206  ...               0.153296
12387               2.327933  ...              -1.012771
12388              -0.180687  ...              -0.048978
12389              -0.240281  ...              -0.042431
[12390 rows x 5 columns]
```

The **result** Df was originally obtained by by appending two dfs

```
result = df1.append(df2)
```

And the row numbers is not a continuation from 0 to 12390, instead it is 0 to 6194 and restarts at 0 to 6194. Could this be the issue?
How do I get the row indices of **result** to continue on df.append?

Comment: `result[['label']]` may this double `[]` cause the problem

Comment: That was a typo, but that was not it. Changing didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it. I had to do `result = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)`, then it would continue the indices. Problem solved.